# htaccess needs to redirect everything including subfolders to index.php whilst keeping URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've looked around for a long time now and up to now no solution seems to work
This is what my setup looks like:
script.js
index.php
.htaccess

I basically have two types of urls that I need redirecting to index.php
1.) localhost:8888/clowns
2.) localhost:8888/clowns/rednose

but I do need the full URL, index.php then loads in the correct pages

This is what I have got already:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

While this works for localhost:8888/clowns
It doesn't work for localhost:8888/clowns/rednose in the sense that index.php is loaded correctly but the scripts it refers to are not.
When I click on script.js it shows that script.js now has the code from index.php

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you including `script.js` in `localhost:8888/clowns/rednose` HTML?

Comment: The folders clowns and rednose do not exist I'm using history.js to generate these urls. But if a customer enters a url with these subfolders the page must redirect to index.php while keeping the full url. index.php then uses the full url to load in the correct text